# Mythbuntu HTPC: disk usage for a normal install

Tags: disk-usage, mythbuntu

about to build a new system, one of the information missing in mythbuntu docs is the disk usage of a typical install for home theather pc (HTPC) usage.

not interested in fresh install or bare bones numbers.

How much does your current system uses? Not counting media, of course, but with all the essentials installed.

This box will probably work for both the backend and frontend.

thanks!

Comment: If you have a lot of space, 20G will be enough for any kind of linux base system.

Comment: i wanted to see something much less than this for mythbuntu... my eeepc uses 4gb for a full debian install, my main desktop has 50gb, but 40gb is android framework and source code of other projects. so roughly 10gb for the system.

Comment: 10G should be fine, just don't install a lot of heavy programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that 150G for all of / is a quite good size. It allows for ample space for games, movies, music etc. while maintaining plenty of room for the OS.

My current install is:

[image: Example Space Usage]

It's worth noting that I have don installs (fully running) in 7G and most of my servers on EC2 have a 10G / and a 40G /home (though there are exceptions based on certain needs).

Comment: hah, mybad... i clicked FAQ on the mythbuntu site and arrived here, searched and posted a question, never realizing it's not a mythbuntu specific site! :D i'm a moron. will edit the question to make it mythbuntu specific. sorry.

Comment: No problem. I have my Mythubuntu install with 200G on / and the rest is stored on a huge external hard drive. Almost nothing on the 200G is uses. You could probably get away with a 40G install if you have your media external.

Comment: thanks again for the input!! my plan so far is to use 2 16gb pen drives until the 120gb ssd arrives :)